# after move reference not same before reference

Tags: rust, ownership

The following is written in the Rust documentation:

> ```
> let s1 = String::from("hello");
> let s2 = s1;
> ```
>
> When we assign s1 to s2, the String data is copied, meaning we copy the pointer, the length, and the capacity that are on the stack. 
>   We do not copy the data on the heap that the pointer refers to.

When I run the following code,

```
let s1 = String::from("aa");
let p2 = &s1;
println!("p2:{:p}", p2);
let s2 = s1;
let p3 = &s2;
println!("p3:{:p}", p3);
```

Output:

```
p2:0x7ffc1bd2e730
p3:0x7ffc1bd2e7a0
```

Why is the address pointed by p2 and the address pointed by p3 not the same?

Comment: Those are the addresses to each of the `String` struct values on the stack, not the string itself. That output pretty much proves that the documentation is correct.

Comment: Why is the address pointed by p2 and the address pointed by p3 should be different ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`s1` is a `struct` that hold:
* the length of the string (i.e. 2 for `aa`)
* the capacity of the string (i.e. at least 2 for `aa`, since there are already 2 characters in there)
* a pointer to the memory containing actual characters

Now, if you move `s1` to `s2`, the length and the capacity and the pointer are transferred to `s2`. But it's nowhere said that `s2` occupies the same location in memory as `s1`. This is what you observe in your program.

*However,* since only the pointer is moved over to `s2`, it still refers to the same memory containing the actual characters. This can be observed by examining `as_bytes`:

```
fn main() {
    let s1 = String::from("aa");
    println!("p2:{:p}", s1.as_bytes());
    let s2 = s1;
    println!("p2:{:p}", s2.as_bytes());
}
```

The above program spits out the same memory address.

Comment: You can also get the same output by writing `&*s1`, or `s1.as_str()`, or any other method to reference the underlying `str` buffer; you don't need to treat it as raw bytes just to observe the address.